# Why my DB date value is comparing incorrectly when I'm querying from knex.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, knex.js

I have a Table called Tasks in my DB. In that there is column called Date and it's ***Date*** type. There are 3 records.
[image: Table Records]

When I'm querying delayed tasks by the todays' date (2020-02-14) output is different than what I expect. So the my knex query is,

```
const delayedTasks = await knex.from('tasks')
          .select('name', 'date')
          .where('agent_id', id)
          .where('date', '<', new Date());
```

But the out put is

```
[
  TextRow { name: 'test task 1', date: 2020-02-13T18:30:00.000Z },
  TextRow { name: 'test task 2', date: 2020-02-11T18:30:00.000Z }
]
```

Expected output,

```
[
  TextRow { name: 'test task 2', date: 2020-02-12T18:30:00.000Z }
]
```

And when I console new Date(),

```
2020-02-14T05:53:15.280Z
```

So my question is why I'm getting query results wrong as in date values wrong in the output ?

Comment: are your DB server zone and web server zone i.e. time zone same? I think there is difference between their timezone. so you are getting issue

Comment: @DeepKakkar no. This is in local machine. Not hosted in a server.

Comment: try to add `.debug()` to the query, it will print the query that Knex generated, run it on your db directly, see if it gives same results

Comment: You got the same problem as me, I still figuring this out why the date reduced by 1 on knex. Do you have any solution?